# Can I use `else if` over `elsif`?

Tags: ruby

1. Is it safe to use `else if` over `elsif`?
2. Is it better to use `elsif` because it follows Ruby's typing
   convention?
3. Or is this a preference?

This is a piece of code taken from a book. I added extra `end` keywords and swapped `elsif` keywords with `else if`s.

```
def describe(inhabitant)
  if inhabitant == "sophie"
    puts 'gender: female'
    puts 'height: 145'
  else if inhabitant == "paul"
    puts 'gender: male'
    puts 'height: 145'
  else if inhabitant == "dawn"
    puts 'gender: female'
    puts 'height: 170'
  else if inhabitant == "brian"
    puts 'gender: male'
    puts 'height: 180'
  else if 
    puts 'species: Trachemys scripta elegans'
    puts 'height: 6'
  end
  end 
  end   
  end
  end
end
```

This made me realize how ugly `else if` is.

Comment: [_I chose 'elsif' as the shortest correct pronounceable word for 'else if'_](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/100350#217027) - matz

Comment: @HunterStevens The book I'm reading is Everyday Scripting with Ruby by Brian Marick. :)

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention I'm using the latest version of Ruby, and thanks!

Comment: Ruby `2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [i386-mingw32]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use `else if` and it's safe. However note that this means extra `end` keywords are needed.

```
if n == 1
  puts "foo"
elsif n == 2
  puts "bar"
end
```

is logically the same as:

```
if n == 1
  puts "foo"
else if n == 2
       puts "bar"
     end
end
```

or the equivalent:

```
if n == 1
  puts "foo"
else 
  if n == 2
    puts "bar"
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, normally, the `else` stands alone and the `else` block is on the next line indented two spaces. If you follow that normal convention (and why shouldn't you, after all `else if` isn't special, because *there is no `else if`*), then it *really* sticks out like a sore thumb.

Comment: I'm now noticing the extra `end` statements. If I was aware of this sooner I would of swapped over to `elsif` in a heartbeat. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Why it is `elsif` but not `elseif` LAMO.

Answer (score 20):

**TL;DR** - Replacing `elsif` with `else if` is alright for a conditional with only 2 paths. Remember to close the second `if` conditional created with `else if`. It is best practice to have as few levels of conditionals as you can, making for a less-complex method. So err on the side of caution and use `elsif`.

Depending on how you plan to write your method, `else if` *may* work. It is not a good habit to get into, however.

Take the following example. There are only 2 conditions. The second condition looks similar to `elsif`, but is interpreted as the second chunk of code:

```
# What you may want to write
if true
  puts 'true'
else if false
  puts 'false'
end

# How Ruby requires it
if true
  puts 'true'
else
  if false  # You may also do: puts 'false' if false
    puts 'false'
  end
end
```

The first block will search for another `end` to close the primary conditional. Take note, you can bypass the extra end with a single line `if` statement. (I only suggest this if the executed code can be written on a single line.)

It is important to note that once you declare an `else`, you may have no other conditionals in the same tier as that `else`. Given the second example above, the second `if` is nested under the `else`. If you were to call `else` or `elsif` on the same tier as the initial `else`, the conditional will fail.

Here is when you would not want to implement `else if`:

```
def describe(inhabitant)
  if inhabitant == "sophie"
    puts 'gender: female'
    puts 'height: 145'
  elsif inhabitant == "paul"
    puts 'gender: male'
    puts 'height: 145'
  elsif inhabitant == "dawn"
    puts 'gender: female'
    puts 'height: 170'
  elsif inhabitant == "brian"
    puts 'gender: male'
    puts 'height: 180'
  else
    puts 'species: Trachemys scripta elegans'
    puts 'height: 6'
  end
end
```

Notice that neither of the `elsif` statements can be "converted" to `else if` in a clean way.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859386/can-i-use-else-if-over-elsif/31859839?noredirect=1#comment51639866_31859839), you can still use `else if`, leading to a very nested method.

https://gist.github.com/sos4nt/a41b36d21f6eec5e0a42

Comment: Converting your last example to `else if` would result in https://gist.github.com/sos4nt/a41b36d21f6eec5e0a42 - that's still clean, just more nested.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer `elsif` over `else if`. But that is just my opinion and technically there is no difference.

But I would suggest to use a `case` block instead of multiple `elsif` your example:

```
def describe(inhabitant)
  case inhabitant
  when "sophie"
    puts 'gender: female'
    puts 'height: 145'
  when "paul"
    puts 'gender: male'
    puts 'height: 145'
  when "dawn"
    puts 'gender: female'
    puts 'height: 170'
  when "brian"
    puts 'gender: male'
    puts 'height: 180'
  else
    puts 'species: Trachemys scripta elegans'
    puts 'height: 6'
  end
```

Or I would store that mapping in a hash:

```
PEOPLE = {
  'sophie' => { :gender => :female, :height => 145 },
  'paul'   => { :gender => :male,   :height => 145 },
  # ...
}

def describe(inhabitant)
  description = PEOPLE.fetch(
    inhabitant, { :species => 'Trachemys scripta elegans', :height => 6 }
  )

  puts "gender: #{description[:gender]}"    if description[:gender]
  puts "species: #{description[:species]}"  if description[:species]
  puts "height: #{description[:height]}"
end
```

Comment: I literally just recommended this to OP in a comment! :-) I refrained from including that in my answer, as I felt it would be a little extraneous to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**You should pick the option that results in better readable code.**  I give below an example of code where I tend to feel that use of `else if` is more readable.

```
result = "Unknown"
error_code = 911

#  Version 1 - uses else if
if result == "Success"
    puts "Good job!"
else
    if error_code == "100"
        puts "No worries, we can still recover"
    else
        puts "Hopeless case!"
    end
end


#  Version 2 - uses elsif
if result == "Success"
    puts "Good job!"
elsif result != "Success" and error_code == "100"
    puts "No worries, we can still recover"
else
    puts "Hopeless case!"
end
```

My guess is this has to do something with [Level of Abstraction](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/06/12/coding-single-level-of-abstraction-principle/). If all the conditions in the `if-elsif-else-end` are at same level, then it will be more readable.  If they are at different levels, it may be beneficial to use few`else if` in the code.